# Reliable way to detect Chrome on Mac in PHP?

Tags: php, browser-detection

As the title says, is there a reliable way to detect whether a user is visiting my page using Chrome on Mac using PHP?

I have a bug that only displays when using Chrome on Mac, and until I get it sorted out I would like to have a popup to recommend the users to use a different browser.

Comment: Why not spend the time implementing this browser popup fixing the bug?

Comment: Because I am a PHP newb and I have exhausted my knowledge trying to figure it out. This means it will take me some time to get it fixed. So a logical thing to do until I have found the issue, is to warn users.

Comment: The logical thing to do would be ask us for help to fix the real problem instead of encouraging your users not to use a sensible browser/OS combination.

Comment: Try to use feature detection instead. If there is a problem that occurs then most likely you can detect that problem by running a short test. That should be much more reliable than guessing which browser the user might be using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] to find the users' user agent and a function to check if this is within the string.

```
//The following will find out whether the user is using a Mac, obviously you can change this by echoing the user agent to find out what you need to search for.
$browser = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "Chrome");
$os = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X");

if($browser !== false && $os !== false) {
  //do stuff if on a mac with Chrome
}
```

This will work with any type of Mac OS X software and any version of Chrome.  If you want to narrow your results down further, you can just use:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] == "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11" ) {
  //do stuff here
}
```

Comment: That browser identity string is not reliable.

Comment: I'm sure for what he's doing - it will be fine.

Comment: If it's not reliable, it's because the user would have changed it. And if he did, he did it voluntarily, so he is responsible for the fact that it's not working.

Comment: Modifications might also occur because of proxies on the way. Apart from that it might also be a new version, a fork, whatever that differs slightly in the footprint. It makes absolutely no sense to invest more and more time into trying hard to detect something that is solved better another way.

Comment: You're detecting all mac users, not mac + chrome users.

Comment: Yes, I don't have Chrome installed to make a super quick response.  All done now.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you posted the code you're having issues with rather than creating a hacky fix.

However, you can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` to check the users browser/OS.

To aid, you would expect something like `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11` from a Mac user on Chrome.

**Note**

The user agent isn't always set so use `isset` first to avoid notices appearing.

Answer (score 0):

I know you're looking for the PHP solution to find the browser, but since the problems you are most likely to encounter with a specific browser are client-side, there should be no need to detect it from the server-side.

So here's a solution with javascript, and if you get the match you expect, you can hide the body, or display a popup, or send it to your server, set a cookie, or whatever you see appropriate to "fix" your problem (although you should be looking into really fixing the problem...)

Look here for [the source](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html):

```
function that_is_called_on_load() {
    if (BrowserDetect.browser == "Chrome" && BrowserDetect.OS == "Mac") {
        alert("You are using mac, sorry.");
        window.location = "mac_chrome.php";
    }
}
```

This is a very "dirty" solution, and it ***might*** be slightly more accurate/reliable than the server-side one.